# Google maps force english language

Tags: google-maps

Hi I would like to know if it is possible to force english as language for google maps.
I have a small application that uses google maps but if I try to use it from a greek browser all the characters are in greece (and the same happen if a friend of mine use it from Egypt the chars are arabic).
Is there any code I can use to solve the problem?
Thank you

Comment: this should answer your question.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351499/how-to-retrieve-english-results-in-google-maps-api-v3][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351499/how-to-retrieve-english-results-in-google-maps-api-v3

Answer (score 20):

You can add certain GET parameters when loading the map, eg `language=en&region=US`. Complete example:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&language=en&region=US
```

For the available options [check the API Docs localisation settings](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/localization).